# wcf config tcp and http

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

hi im working on wcf that has http + tcp services
thats my config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://localhost/API/"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>

<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>

<services>
  <service name="API.APIsrv" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">

    <endpoint address="http://localhost/tAPI/Basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Basic" bindingConfiguration="Basic" contract="API.IAPIsrv" >
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="http://localhost/API" binding="webHttpBinding" name="APIsrv" contract="API.IAPIsrv" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/API"  binding="netTcpBinding" name="APIsrv.netTcpBinding" contract="API.IAPIsrv">
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="http://localhost/API/mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />

    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/API/mex"
              binding="mexTcpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost/API/APIsrv.svc"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Basic" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="APIsrv.netTcpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="20480000">
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>

</bindings>
```

in my global file i handle route address:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(APIsrv)));
    }
```

in my local client test i get this error:
The service '/API/' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The ChannelDispatcher at 'http://localhost/API/Basic' with contract(s) '"IAPIsrv"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.

how can i fix this issue

Comment: Can you post the inner exception as well - this is quite a wide ranging error... :)

Comment: Yep, we would love some more info in order to help with this.

Comment: ok i managed to go abit forword but now my error is on the client wcf The .Net Framing mode being used is not supported by 'net.tcp://api.svc'. See the server logs for more details.